# Dart program not exiting

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I'm having trouble tracking down why my dart program isn't terminating. I'm pretty sure it's something to do with either isolates, or stream controllers, and making sure they are closed, but I can't work out what the problem is.

On all of my `StreamController`s i'm calling `await streamControllerName.close();`, but I think there is an isolate closing mechanism that I don't know about. Would there be any reason why the event loop isn't finishing and so the program isn't exiting? Difficult to give more details as the code is quite long.

Comment: Do you have any ReceivePort open?

Comment: yes there are `n` receive ports open where `n` is the number of isolates i spawn. Do these need to be closed?

Comment: Yes, they need to be closed. At least in the main isolate.

Comment: legend. That sorted my problem! Thank you so much. If you add an answer i'll accept it. Is it potentially a source of memory leaks if the receive ports are left open, or are they automatically closed after a while?

Comment: They are not closed automatically, so you need to close them when you are done with them. But you can also just reuse them if you want since you can create as many `SendPort` you want pointing to a given `ReceivePort`.

Comment: Ok. So it could potentially be a memory leak if I were to leave them open when I don't want to reuse them? Not quite sure what you mean by pointing many send ports to a give receive port. I'm creating a load of channels for communication between the main isolate and worker isolates, but if I do `IsolateChannel.connectReceive(rPort)` multiple times on the same `rPort` object of type `ReceivePort`, I get `Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.`

Comment: What I mean is that the `sendPort` property on `ReceivePort` can be sent to as many isolates you want and at the same time. You can therefore have many isolates sending data to the same `ReceivePort` but you can only subscribe once on a `ReceivePort` (unless you make it a broadcast Stream. See the note in the documentation: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-isolate/ReceivePort-class.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dart programs stops when the main isolate has nothing left to do (so no code is executing and no events on the event or microtask queues) and nothing is subscribed to which can spawn events into the main isolate.

Besides `Timer` which can spawn delayed events, we have `ReceivePort` which allow us to send events into an isolate from another isolate. It should be noted that Dart does not keep track of the relationship between a `ReceivePort` and `SendPort` instances pointing to that `ReceivePort`.

This means that Dart does not know when a `ReceivePort` is no longer "in use" and it is therefore up to the developer to ensure closing any open `ReceivePort`  by calling the `close()` method on each instance (notice that `SendPort` does not have any `close()` method) when they are no longer in use.

As long as there are any open `ReceivePort` in the main isolate, the program will continue running since an event might be spawned from one of these `ReceivePort` instances.