# Why the exitPort hander `if` statement isn't called at the very end

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

In the below program the `printTest` method must be called at the end after all Isolates have finished but why is `printTest` method called before the isolates have finished. This condition checks `if (--liveIsolates == 0)` weather isolates have finished executing.

The `Test` class instance is used to check weather the instance is same inside of different isolates.

### Source

---

```
import "dart:isolate";

Test test = Test();

void main(final List<String> args) async {
  final exitPort = RawReceivePort();
  const int numberOfIsolates = 1000;
  int liveIsolates = 0;

  exitPort.handler = (_) {
    print("Entering handler");

    final alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqurstuvwxyz";
    print("$alpha $alpha $alpha $_");
    if (--liveIsolates == 0) {
      printTest();
      print("Closing the exitPort");
      exitPort.close();
    }

    print("Exiting handler");
  };

  liveIsolates = numberOfIsolates;

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIsolates; i++) { // creating multiple isolates
    final isolate1 =
        await Isolate.spawn(foo, exitPort.sendPort, onExit: exitPort.sendPort);
  }

  print("Exiting main");
}

void foo(final SendPort sendPort) {
  sendPort.send("Data to be send from foo");
  print("Entering foo sendPort id ${sendPort.hashCode}");
  test++;
  print("Exiting foo id test : ${test.hashCode}");
  print("Exiting foo id test : $test");
}

void printTest() { // should be called @ last by exitPort handler
  print("Value of test : $test");
}

class Test {
  int _data = 0;

  void set(int value) => _data = value;

  int get data => _data;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return _data.toString();
  }

  Test operator +(int _) { // overloading ++ operator
    _data++;
    return this;
  }
}
```

---

Why the below lines of statement is executed before all the isolates have finished? From the output of the above program we can see that this statement `Closing the exitPort` is displayed at in between instead of @ the very bottom.

```
if (--liveIsolates == 0) {
      printTest();
      print("Closing the exitPort");
      exitPort.close();
    }
```

Comment: You are aware that you are using `exitPort.sendPort` twice here: `Isolate.spawn(foo, exitPort.sendPort, onExit: exitPort.sendPort)`. So your `exitPort.handler = (_) {` are getting triggered two times for each isolate, first by the message sent with `sendPort.send("Data to be send from foo")` and then later when the isolate are getting killed. But since `if (--liveIsolates == 0)` will subtract the `liveIsolates` each time when asked, then you are ending up subtracting twice for each isolate and your condition ends up being true after half of your isolates are done running. Is this intentional?

Comment: @julemand101 you are correct I didn't realized that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the comments, the issue with the current code is the following line:

```dart
await Isolate.spawn(foo, exitPort.sendPort, onExit: exitPort.sendPort);
```

Where `exitPort.sendPort` are being used twice, both for getting messages from the spawned `Isolate` and then also when the `Isolate` are stopping.

By the current code, `exitPort.sendPort` gets sent two messages for each `Isolate` but `exitPort.handler` is designed to only receive one message for each spawned `Isolate` in its countdown logic.

This means the following gets called way too early:

```dart
      exitPort.close();
```

Since the main `Isolate` then no longer waits for any further communication with isolates, the Dart process are likely to be stopped early since Dart since Dart will not automatically wait for all spawned `Isolate` being executed. See the following for more detailed explanation about when Dart programs are stopped:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70670962/1953515