# The compute method is not executed completely when I use `List.generate` inside of it but when I use forloop the compute method is executed completely

Tags: loops, dart, dart-isolates

The below program is for understanding `isolates` in `dart`. The `compute` method is passed to the spawned isolate. Inside of `compute` method summation is performed but when `List.generate` is used the `compute` function doesn't finish the execution because the `print("The total sum is : $sum");` statement is never called.

Instead of using `List.generate` if we use simple `for loop` (commented line of code in `compute()`) the `sum` is calculated and also displayed.

```
import "dart:isolate";

void main(final List<String> args) async {
  print("Entering main");
  final model = ModelClass(35000, 100);
  await Isolate.spawn<ModelClass>(compute, model);
  print("Exiting main");
}

void compute(final ModelClass model) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int value in List.generate(model.iteration, (index) => index)) {
    sum += value * model.multiplier;
  }
  // for (int index = 0; index < model.iteration; index++) {
  //   sum += index * model.multiplier;
  // }
  print("The total sum is : $sum");
}

class ModelClass {
  final int iteration;
  final int multiplier;

  ModelClass(this.iteration, this.multiplier);
}
```

Why when we use `List.generate` to generate a `list` and iterate over it the `compute` function doesn't finish execution?

Comment: I'm not an expert on Dart isolates, but I think that this is simply because the version with the basic `for`-loop is faster than the `List.generate` version, so it manages to complete before the program terminates.  As written, I don't think that the main isolate will wait for the spawned isolate to complete.  I think that you can observe the `compute` function completing if you add a delay before exiting `main`.

Comment: Correct. The program ends when the main isolate exits. It does that after printing "Exiting main". The other isolate dies with it, after having done some, but not necessarily all, of its work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the following does not `await` the spawned `Isolate` being done executing. Instead, it will just `await` on the creation of the `Isolate` itself.

```dart
await Isolate.spawn<ModelClass>(compute, model);
```

After this, your main `Isolate` have nothing else to do and does not have any way to later get triggered by any kind of event (e.g. from `RecievePort`, `Timer` or similar).

Dart will therefore quit your program since your programs execution is only depended on the mail `Isolate`. See the following answer for a more detailed description of when Dart programs stops and does not stop: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70670962/1953515

But in short, you need to make your `main` Isolate wait for some answer back from your spawned isolates if you want your program to first being stopped after all isolates are done execution.

The `compute()` function in Flutter is doing that since it is designed to run a given function in a separate `Isolate` and then return the result back to the caller isolate. So it will automatically setup a `RecievePort`/`SendPort` pair.

In Dart, you can do the same with the newly introduced `Isolate.run` introduced in Dart 2.19:
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.6/dart-isolate/Isolate/run.html