# Dart VM exits with no exception/no message -- expecting a deadlock

Tags: dart

I was playing with Dart's Futures and Completers and ran into something unexpected IMHO.

The behavior happens when a completer has been created and futures are awaiting for this completer's future, but the completer never gets a chance to complete. I was expecting a deadlock and the program should never exit.

But it does stop, with no exception/message displayed. I've tried adding listeners to the isolate's error and exit handlers to try understand what's happening: now the program deadlocks.

Any idea what's happening here? I suspect installing the listeners impacts the event loop one way or another, so Dart continues executing (exhibiting the deadlock situation). But why does Dart exit (with no message) when there are no listeners?

The sample code is a bit long, I've created a gist for it: https://gist.github.com/d-markey/67cdffa57f948a0097ac556b93c7b373

Comment: I've added a periodic timer to display a message every second, now the program always deadlocks.

Comment: Maybe worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70670962/1953515

Answer (score 2):

This is working as expected.

Awaiting a future is not a blocking action. It registers a callback on the future, then goes back to the event loop and happily continues running the program.

When the event loop is empty, and there are no open ports or timers or anything else that may happen, the program ends. Nothing is happening, and nothing can *make* something happen, so the runtime concludes that there is no reason to keep running.
That's how a program will usually end, so nothing new or exciting about that.

Having a callback set on a future somewhere does nothing to change this behavior. Until that future completes, that's just *data*, and it won't prevent the program from closing any more than the future itself would.
Nothing is *actively waiting* for the future to complete, asynchronous events are *push* based, they happen when something makes them happen. If nothing happens, that is it.